# Issue in Windows 10 with lack of icon transparency for System icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, transparency

[image: icon-transparency-issue]

Just started using Windows 10 and I'm seeing that system icons are not transparent and instead I'm seeing the white and grey placeholder background (chequerboard) you usually see to indicate a background is transparent.

Other icons such as the Chrome icon are unaffected by this issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a MysticThumbs issue, with old versions that did not support Windows 10 PNG. Newest versions as of [version 3.4.0](https://mysticcoder.net/MysticThumbsHistory.aspx#build340) do support Windows 10. The issue is caused when a PNG from the "Metro" side of things went through MysticThumbs and PNG was set to the old default transparency mode 'Light Checkerboard' they would have the checkerboard background added. These PNG's are now recognised by the newer versions and always made with transparency.

Another option when using MysticThumbs is to either set PNG to transparent in the MysticThumbs control panel, or to disable PNG support in the control panel altogether, depending on your needs.

After fixing things, use the 'Clear Thumbnail Cache' option in MysticThumbs control panel or tray icon and optionally restart Explorer and or Windows to force a flush.

As noted in the comments it appears Windows may have a hidden cache for HiDPI modes that does not get cleared implicitly with a cache clear. Changing your DPI settings to 100% and then back again should fix this.

Comment: As well as clearing the thumbnail cache you may need to kickstart Windows 10 into refreshing the icons it has cached elsewhere such as from any search results when looking for an installed app. You can do this by changing your zoom level to 125% and back again (under Display Settings from the Desktop right click menu).

Answer (score 0):

It was reported that programs like Icaros thumbs and SageThumbs can be the cause...
http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1266764-windows-10-taskbar-icons-look-awful/?page=2

> <sup>Chances are it's caused by a shell extension like SageThumbs, Icaros or Media Preview. I have SageThumbs, which I use primarily to give Photoshop docs thumbnails, but I found it was also messing with the thumbnail icons of these ModernUI apps, which are stored as .pngs.</sup>
>   <sub>I disabled SageThumbs and deleted the thumbnail cache (run cleanmgr.exe), and after a restart, all the icons look like they should, and they show up when searching in the Start menu too.</sub>

I solved mine by restoring PNG format, just download the png.reg, apply and restart explorer process.
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Thanks @Belgari: your solution pointed me in the right direction. I use MysticThumbs for thumbnail previews for various file types and disabling on `*.png` and clearing the thumbnail cache solved the transparency issue I was seeing. Will log the bug with MysticThumbs for `*.png` on Windows 10.

Comment: Updating to MysticThumbs `3.4.3` fixes PNG support in Windows 10